# Slow pug compiling to HTML

Tags: javascript, gulp, pug

I'm using gulp to compile my pug file to HTML. It takes an average of 30 seconds each time I make any kind of change! Is it maybe due to something in my gulp config (listed below)?

```
var gulp   = require('gulp')
var pug = require('gulp-pug')

gulp.task('pug', function () {
  return gulp.src('pug/**/*.pug')
    .pipe(pug({pretty:true, doctype:'HTML'}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('views'))
})

gulp.task('watch:pug', ['pug'], function () {
  gulp.watch('pug/**/*.pug', ['pug'])
})
```

Comment: Does this solve your problem?

Answer (score 5):

If it is the `pug` compilation that slows you down, add caching.

```
var gulp     = require('gulp');
var pug      = require('gulp-pug');
var cached   = require('gulp-cached');
var remember = require('gulp-remember');

gulp.task('pug', function () {
  return gulp.src('pug/**/*.pug', { since: gulp.lastRun('pug') }))
    .pipe(cached('pug'))
    .pipe(pug({pretty:true, doctype:'HTML'}))
    .pipe(remember('pug'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('views'))
})

gulp.task('watch', function(done) {
  gulp.watch('pug/**/*.pug', gulp.parallel('pug'));
  return done();
});

gulp.task('default', gulp.series('pug', 'watch'));
```

The option `gulp.lastRun` will only return files that were changed since the last run of the given task. If you use the `default` task to build your files, `pug` will only need to process the files that were changed. Because the gulp process is kept alive by the watch function, it is able to cache all previous unchanged files.

**REMARK**: This will only work if you use Gulp v4, if not, you should really upgrade ;)

### Solution for Gulp < 4.0

There is a package called [`gulp-cache`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-cached), which `{ since: gulp.lastRun('pug') }`. So you should be able to adjust the snippet:

```
var gulp     = require('gulp');
var pug      = require('gulp-pug');
var cache    = require('gulp-cache');
var cached   = require('gulp-cached');
var remember = require('gulp-remember');

gulp.task('pug', function () {
  return gulp.src('pug/**/*.pug'))
    .pipe(cache('pug'))
    .pipe(cached('pug'))
    .pipe(pug({pretty:true, doctype:'HTML'}))
    .pipe(remember('pug'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('views'))
})

gulp.task('watch', function(done) {
  gulp.watch('pug/**/*.pug', ['pug']);
  return done();
});

gulp.task('default', ['pug', 'watch']);
```

I am not sure if you really need `gulp-cached` and `gulp-remember`. Those packages link the input files to converted output files. This means `gulp-remember` will output all files that were processed. If the file was not updated, it will output the cached version. If you don't need all files (e.g. because you are not concatenating them), you could remove those lines.

Even if the package names are very similar, they are completely different:

The package `gulp-cache` will only forward files that have changed since the last build. It essentially does the same, then the option `{ sine: gulp.lastRun('pug') }`.

So if you need to process the files further down in your pipe, you need all 3 packages, otherwise, the package `gulp-cache` (without **d**) should be sufficient.

Comment: Seems like a good idea but unfortunately, I'm not able at the moment to upgrade Gulp to v4..Is none of this task available in v3.9?

Comment: @RomainGaget i've updated the answer. But the solution is untested.

Comment: Awesome, it works actually with adding cached and remember.The compiling time went from 40 seconds to 3 seconds!!Thank you @Iqon

Comment: Great! In that case, i will remove the __untested__ tag.

Comment: Does this method update the pug file which has dependencies on modified files? I have tried gulp-cache before and it only parsed the modified file and didn't change the file which imported them which didn't help at all.

Answer (score 0):

I using this.

Only pass through changed files

No more wasting precious time on processing unchanged files.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-changed